# Matlab - Defining the maximum value of a slider with a pushbutton_callback

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a GUI. Suppose I want to display a certain number of images. I created a slider to display all the images in one window when you scroll down. The problem occurrs when you scroll down and exceed the number of images, so I need something to control the maximum value of the slider

One solution to this is:

I can create a slider in certain position and with certain max depending on images I selected .

My code right now (does not have the solution I spoke about) :

```
function varargout = panel(varargin)


gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @panel_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @panel_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end


function panel_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
handles.output = hObject;

guidata(hObject, handles);


function varargout = panel_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

varargout{1} = handles.output;


function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global celldata3;
k = 1;
[filename pathname]  = uigetfile({'*.*'},'File Selector','MultiSelect', 'on')
iscellstr(filename)
celldata1 = cellstr(pathname)
celldata2 = cellstr(filename)
celldata3 = strcat(celldata1,celldata2)
subplot(3,4,1),imshow(celldata3{1})
subplot(3,4,2),imshow(celldata3{2})
subplot(3,4,3),imshow(celldata3{3})
subplot(3,4,4),imshow(celldata3{4})
subplot(3,4,5),imshow(celldata3{5})
subplot(3,4,6),imshow(celldata3{6})
subplot(3,4,7),imshow(celldata3{7})
subplot(3,4,8),imshow(celldata3{8})
subplot(3,4,9),imshow(celldata3{9})
subplot(3,4,10),imshow(celldata3{10})
subplot(3,4,11),imshow(celldata3{11})
subplot(3,4,12),imshow(celldata3{12})



function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global celldata3;
a = get(hObject,'Value')
b = get(hObject,'Max')
[n max] = size(celldata3)
%set(handles.text2,'string',a)
i = (b-a)*4

if i+12 >= max
  display ('STOP!');
end

subplot(3,4,1),imshow(celldata3{i+1})
subplot(3,4,2),imshow(celldata3{i+2})
subplot(3,4,3),imshow(celldata3{i+3})
subplot(3,4,4),imshow(celldata3{i+4})
subplot(3,4,5),imshow(celldata3{i+5})
subplot(3,4,6),imshow(celldata3{i+6})
subplot(3,4,7),imshow(celldata3{i+7})
subplot(3,4,8),imshow(celldata3{i+8})
subplot(3,4,9),imshow(celldata3{i+9})
subplot(3,4,10),imshow(celldata3{i+10})
subplot(3,4,11),imshow(celldata3{i+11})
subplot(3,4,12),imshow(celldata3{i+12})
display (i+12)

function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end


function slider1_ButtonDownFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

Comment: So your question is actually : How to set the maximal value for a slider? is that it?

Comment: yes that's acceptable also

Comment: Can you just assign the `Max` property of the slide during its creation, in its `Opening_Fcn`?Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#zmw57dd0e730587)

Comment: you'll have to be more explicit than "_i tried couldn't_" ... where in the code did you try, what error are you getting, etc ?